# hql - order by first item of the list

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql

So I have a requirement that would need me to order the results by the id of the first item of the list.

```
public class Order {
private int id;
private List<Item> items;
}
```

To get an order where the list items contains '1234', I can do something like this:

```
from Order o where o.items[0].id = 1234
```

Back to my requirement, I thought this would work but it didn't:

```
from Order o order by o.items[0].id
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I tried that before; and I don't think it is possible to do it through a list. If you had another column that is Item, then you can do it like order by o.item.id or if you add Item table to the join then order that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the least id value of `item` wouldn't this do what you want?

```
select distinct o from Order o join o.items item order by item.id
```